# Trying to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos^3(x)} \,dx$ and got stuck

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

So, I am trying to evaluate the following anti-derivative:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos^3(x)} \,dx$$

I reached a point where I have the following:

$$\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^3(x)} + \frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} \,dx$$

My idea now is to calculate two separate anti derivatives from here. I am using wolfram alpha to try to help me solve the anti derivative btw. but when I put on Wolfram this anti derivative:

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} \,dx$$

the result is not the same as:

$$\int \frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)} \,dx$$

Why is that?? How can I solve this indefinite integral?

Comment: "solve" is the wrong word, but seems to be one of those words used when people don't know which word to use. "Evaluate" is the right word. One solves equations; one solves problems; one _evaluates_ expressions.

Comment: How did you conclude the result is not the same? Two expressions that look different may be the same. That happens often with trigonometric functions.

Comment: The antiderivative of $\dfrac 1 {\sin x\cos x} = \dfrac 2 {\sin(2x)}$ is one of the hardest antiderivatives to find using first-year calculus methods. Except for details is essentially the same as finding the antiderivative of the secant function.

Comment: Thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the integral as
$$\int \sec^3(x)\csc(x)\,dx$$
Make the substitution $u=\tan x$, then $du=\sec^2(x) \,dx$, and it is
$$\int \sec(x)\csc(x)\,du$$
$$\int u+\frac{1}{u}\,du ~~~~ \text{(why?)}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: If I understood correctly, is $sec(x)csc(x)$ the same as $$\frac{sinx}{cosx} \frac{cosx}{sinx}$$ ?

Comment: $\sec(x)=\frac{1}{\cos(x)}, \csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, then $$\tan(x)+\frac{1}{\tan(x)}=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}+\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos(x)}=\sec(x)\csc(x)$$

Comment: so, why can we u-substitute with $tan(x)$? EDIT: ahh, ok. Makes total sense!

Comment: If you're asking for the motivation, I wanted to reduce the power of $\sec(x)$, and noted that the derivative of tangent is secant squared.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that$$\int\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^3(x)}\,\mathrm dx=-\frac{\cos^{-2}(x)}{-2}=\frac1{2\cos^2(x)}$$and that\begin{align}\int\frac1{\sin(x)\cos(x)}\,\mathrm dx&=\int\frac{\sin(x)}{(1-\cos^2(x))\cos(x)}\,\mathrm dx\\&=-\log|\cos x|+\frac12\log(1-\cos^2(x))\\&=-\log|\cos x|+\log|\sin x|\\&=\log|\tan x|.\end{align}

Comment: Can you explain me why is $-log|cosx|+log|sinx|=log|tanx|$?

Comment: \begin{align}-\log|\cos x|+\log|\sin x|&=\log|\sin x|-\log|\cos x|\\&=\log\frac{|\sin x|}{|\cos x|}\\&=\log|\tan x|.\end{align}

Comment: of COURSE!!! ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

With your great answers I was able to evaluate this integral as follows:

$$
\int \frac{1}{\sin(x)\cos^3(x)}  \,dx = \int \sec^3(x)\csc(x)  \,dx =\\
\int \sec(x)\csc(x) \sec^2(x)  \,dx = \int \frac{1}{\cos(x)\sin(x)} \sec^2(x) \,dx = \\
\int \frac{\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)}{\cos(x)\sin(x)} \sec^2(x) \,dx = \int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} + \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} \sec^2(x) \,dx = \\
\int \tan(x) +\cot(x)  \sec^2(x) \,dx = \int \tan(x) + \frac{1}{\tan(x)}  \sec^2(x) \,dx\\ 
u=\tan(x)\\du=\sec^2(x)dx\\
\int u +\frac{1}{u} \,du = \frac{u^2}{2}+\ln|u|+c =\\
\frac{1}{2}\tan^2(x)+\ln|\tan(x)| +c
$$

Thank you everybody for your helpful answers and comments.

Comment: use <\trigfunction(foo).  That is, within mathjax, \sin(x), \cos(x), \sec(x), \cosec (x), \tan(x), \cot(x).  Also, \ln.  Else they look  grossly italicized.  Else, good job.

Comment: thanks for the tip!

Comment: Glad to help!  It can take awhile to get the hang of mathjax.  In general, \function(argument) is a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Nice job!!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\quad \int \frac{1}{\sin x \cos ^3 x} d x&=\int \frac{\cos ^2 x+\sin ^2 x}{\sin x \cos ^3 x} d x\\
&=\int \frac{1}{\sin x \cos x} d x+\int \tan x \sec ^2 x d x\\
&=\int \frac{d(\tan x)}{\tan x}+\int \tan x d(\tan x)\\
&=\ln |\tan x| +\frac{\tan ^2 x}{2}+C
\end{aligned}
$$